# USB Smart Card Reader Connection Issues

Tags: ubuntu, usb, smartcard

I've recently begun working on a smart card reader connection issue in a company I'm working as an intern.

The reader in question is a DUAli DE-620 using the CCID driver, and I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04. Both in a vm version and a live in installation, there seems to be an issue in the USB layer resulting in the following dmesg output;

```
[ 5840.680206] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 73 using xhci_hcd
[ 5840.829516] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 5840.829521] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5840.829524] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 5840.829526] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 5840.829529] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 5840.852392] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 73
[ 5841.456266] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 74 using xhci_hcd
[ 6352.804091] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
[ 6352.953382] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 6352.953387] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6352.953390] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 6352.953393] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 6352.953395] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 6352.977508] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 75
[ 6353.580077] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
[ 6353.729268] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 6353.729273] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6353.729276] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 6353.729279] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 6353.729291] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 6353.750710] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 76
[ 6354.352054] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
[ 6354.501314] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 6354.501319] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6354.501322] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 6354.501325] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 6354.501328] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 6354.524734] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 77
[ 6355.128030] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[ 6355.277316] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 6355.277321] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6355.277324] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 6355.277326] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 6355.277329] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 6355.300066] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 78
[ 6355.904009] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
[ 6356.053320] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1db2, idProduct=0630
[ 6356.053326] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6356.053329] usb 3-2: Product: DE-620
[ 6356.053331] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: DUALi
[ 6356.053334] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B71468D80508
[ 6356.076448] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 79
[ 6356.679934] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 80 using xhci_hcd
```

and it goes on and on as long as the device is connected. Following commands also do not show the VID and PID in dmesg output

```
lsusb 
usb-devices
```

The device in question works fine in an all-in-one OpenSUSE PC and my secondary boot Win10 but has this issue in Ubuntu 16.04. Attempts at resolving the issue can be found [here](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/pcsclite-muscle/2018-September/001108.html) and I've also tried a different cable as well.

What might be happening in the USB layer that can cause this and what might I do to fix this?

EDIT: As per comments lspci -nn output is as follows;

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] [10de:0fd2] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
02:00.2 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 MS Card Reader [14e4:16be] (rev 10)
02:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 xD-Picture Card Reader [14e4:16bf] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
```

EDIT 2: using wireshark with usbmon showed multiple attempts of trying to get the device descriptors and configurations looping until the hub disconnects the device

EDIT 3: pcscd log is as follows;

```
$ sudo LIBCCID_ifdLogLevel=0x000F pcscd --foreground --debug --apdu --color | tee log.txt
[sudo] password for g: 
00000000 debuglog.c:291:DebugLogSetLevel() debug level=debug
00000116 debuglog.c:312:DebugLogSetCategory() Debug options: APDU
00000015 pcscdaemon.c:268:main() Force colored logs
00000052 utils.c:84:GetDaemonPid() Can't open /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.pid: No such file or directory
00000092 configfile.l:283:DBGetReaderListDir() Parsing conf directory: /etc/reader.conf.d
00000040 configfile.l:317:DBGetReaderListDir() Skipping non regular file: ..
00000027 configfile.l:355:DBGetReaderList() Parsing conf file: /etc/reader.conf.d/libccidtwin
00000063 configfile.l:317:DBGetReaderListDir() Skipping non regular file: .
00000008 pcscdaemon.c:569:main() pcsc-lite 1.8.14 daemon ready.
00034133 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/003/001
00000144 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0003, path: /dev/bus/usb/004/001
00000143 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000109 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/001
00000113 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000117 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0489, PID: 0xE04E, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000106 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x0489, PID: 0xE04E, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/003
00000075 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000080 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x04F2, PID: 0xB374, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00000079 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x04F2, PID: 0xB374, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/004
00000075 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
00000106 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/001
00000071 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1D6B, PID: 0x0002, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/001
00000076 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/002
00000081 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x045E, PID: 0x0752, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/003
00000075 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/002
00000080 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x046D, PID: 0xC534, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/004
00000079 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x046D, PID: 0xC534, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/004
00000075 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/002
21798580 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000327 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/124
00001155 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01029546 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000371 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/125
00001006 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01032328 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000627 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/126
00001079 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01030744 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000763 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/127
00000925 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01025636 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000639 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/005
00001115 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01030189 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000566 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/006
00001229 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01030823 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000565 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x1DB2, PID: 0x0630, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/007
00001138 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
01031152 hotplug_libudev.c:623:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device add
00000403 hotplug_libudev.c:296:get_driver() Looking for a driver for VID: 0x8087, PID: 0x0024, path: /dev/bus/usb/002/002
00001134 hotplug_libudev.c:617:HPEstablishUSBNotifications() USB Device removed
```

EDIT: The problem was due to the usb drivers in the latest kernel, commenting NTP relevant code fixed the issue.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that it works under Win10 with exactly the same hardware as Ubuntu? If not, unexplainable disconnects are sometimes due to power issues, so try attaching the device behind a powered hub. I also see it's a full-speed (USB 2.0) device on a super-speed (xhci, USB 3.0) root hub, so if the root hub driver (whatever your hardware is) is buggy, try it on a legacy USB 2.0 root hub (if you have any). Another thing to do is to use `wireshark` together with `usbmon` to snoop the USB traffic, maybe this will give an indication what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes works with the exact hardware under Win10. Well the port I'm connecting it to on my lap top is supposed to be USB 2.0 but something weird is happening and xhci is taking over, a kernel issue maybe? Will take a look at wireshark and post the results as well.

Comment: the device is still cycling even when forced to use ehci-pci

Comment: So a bug in the root hub driver is unlikely (also, the Intel root hubs are used everywhere, it'd shown sooner). Power issue is unlikely if it works with same HW under Win 10. Which leaves the CCID driver screwing up as possible reason. I'd still try wireshark next. Just googled, is the CCID driver not part of the standard kernel? Which driver are you using? Can you enable debugging mode for the driver?

Comment: If you a using [this one](https://ccid.apdu.fr), it explains the commandline args to produce a full log on the linked page.

Comment: I used wireshark but don't know how to post the results here. I am using CCID's latest along with pcscd, the log is in post.

Comment: also the problem also exists in a fresh install of ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out NTP code in the kernel fixed the issue, apparently the device got itself in an infinite loop because of rules added in Linux kernel 4.*